# Juice UI Draggable Controls

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

Using Juice UI draggable controls, I can easily make an update panel draggable as the code on their website suggests as follows:

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="upFormControl" CssClass="box">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </asp:Panel>
    <Juice:Draggable ID="Draggable1" runat="server" TargetControlID="upFormControl" />
```

It seems to me that I can only make an update panel draggable, no other controls seem to work.  i did change the ID and the TargetControlID and it all works fine. so my logic tells me the following code should work with a button:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <Juice:Draggable ID="Draggable2" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" />
```

But it does not.  There is no documentation or help on these issues from Juice UI.  If anyone has any experience with this and could tell me that it will not work with other controls, or even better, tell me how to go about getting it to work with other controls, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew) a try, might resolve the issue. It's a fork of Juice UI.